# Where to perform controller initialization that relies on user being authenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've found a bug in our application caused when the user's authentication ticket expires.

The controller is decorated with the Authorize attribute but we were doing some initialization of variables in the controller's constructor which relied on the user being authenticated.

So where would be the best place to move this initialization code to such that it is not executed if the user is not authenticated (and therefore they will be redirected to the login page)? OnAuthorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So where would be the best place to move this initialization code to
>   such that it is not executed if the user is not authenticated

You could write a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` and perform it inside the [`AuthorizeCore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore.aspx) method (after calling the base method and ensuring that it returned `true`).

Another possibility is to write a custom model binder to some model which will initialize it and then your controller actions could take this model as argument.

Comment: I'm initializing variables used only within the controller. It's just basically to save me doing it within every controller action. Looking into it, OnActionExecuting should be fine for this, since this won't fire if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: @Ben, what kind of information those variables hold? Maybe a repository would be a better place to perform this initialization? `OnActionExecuting` could indeed be another place in which you perform this initialization but it is specific to a given controller and not reusable among different controllers (unless they derive from a base controller).

Comment: It's actually information we are pulling out of a repository. Since we need that information for every action it just saves us repeating code. I'll swap this out for a modelbinder at some point so this is really just temporary. The downside of OnActionExecuting however is it seems to fire before one of my ActionFilters OnActionExecuting event.

Comment: @Ben, indeed a custom model binder seems like a great place to perform this initialization. I have updated my answer with this.

Comment: is the controller's OnActionExecuting event always fired before an ActionFilter's?

Comment: Yes, the controller's `OnActionExecuting` is executed before `OnActionExecuting` methods of action filters. There are `IAuthorizationFilter`, `IActionFilter`, `IResultFilter`, `IExceptionFilter` which are executed in this order.